# Can someone please explain the type of params array in my case in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have seen someone created params array and the end result is the following:

```js
buildparams(query) {
    let params = [];
    if (query) {
      let vars = query.split('&');
      for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        let pair = vars[i].split('=');
        params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]); 
      }
    }
    return params;
  }  
  
  let params = this.buildparams(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.fragment);
  console.log(params );

//The params looks like this
//params = [access_token: "abcd", iss: "Test111", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: "4799", client_id: "TestClientId"];
```

What kind of array is it and why length is 0 when I console it. The proper array should be like:

```js
house = ["1BHK", "2BHK", "3BHK", "4BHK"];
```

Can someone please explain the type of params array?

Why and how does the code even allow adding pair[0] not integer value in the first place with let params = [];? There should be an error thrown here by the compiler but not in my case.

Comment: The end result is a SyntaxError.

Comment: Arrays are objects. When you add a new key to it with bracket/dot notation you're just adding another key to the object. So `params` is still an array (which internally is an object), that has keys custom keys added to it. Usually you would just us an object literal instead of an array.

Comment: Change it to `let params = {}`. https://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **length** of your `params` array is 0 because it won't have elements in it because the code is buggy.

Actually this is not valid Javascript:

```
params = [access_token: "abcd", iss: "Test111", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: "4799", client_id: "TestClientId"];
```

```js
const s = "access_token=abcd&iss=Test111&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=4799&client_id=TestClientId";

function buildparams(query) {
  let params = {}; // this has to be an object, not an array
  if (query) {
    let vars = query.split('&');
    for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      let pair = vars[i].split('=');
      params[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
    }
  }
  return params;
}

let params = buildparams(s);
console.log(params);

//The params looks like this
//params = [access_token: "abcd", iss: "Test111", token_type: "Bearer", expires_in: "4799", client_id: "TestClientId"];
```

If `pair[0]` is allowed to be not an **integer**, then `params` in the function should not be an `Array` (in most cases it would be an `Object`, but there are other possibilities, for example, `Map` (you assign items to `Map` differently though)).

Comment: Why and how does the code even allow adding pair[0] not integer value in the first place with let params = [];? There should be an error thrown here by the compiler but not in my case.

Comment: @KarimAli this is not an error. It's accessing a property of an `Object` with `[]`. Totally valid to say `someObject["key"]` instead of `someObject.key`. You could not make dynamic keys otherwise, for example. Don't forget that in Javascript (almost) everything is an `Object` - even `Array`s